# C++ variable equals not variable

Tags: c++

```
generate = !generate;
```

I saw this in the generateGaussianNoise function here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform

```
double generateGaussianNoise(double mu, double sigma)
{
    static const double epsilon = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    static const double two_pi = 2.0*3.14159265358979323846;

    thread_local double z1;
    thread_local bool generate;
    generate = !generate;
```

I don't understand the logic of this: variable = !variable;

coming from a Python background. Can someone explain?

One specific question: I would expect `generate = True` to be somewhere here bbut I don't see it.

Two specific question:

```
if (!generate)
   return z1 * sigma + mu;
```

How can this code work if z1 is not assigned until AFTER this piece of code?

Comment: They negate the value in generate, e.g. i suppose it is a bool. If it was `true`, then after that it is `false`, and if it was `false`, then it is `true` after the statement

Comment: Please see my update. Generate is never assigned to any true or false value

Comment: The variable `generate` probably acts as a *flag*, and the assignment *toggles* the flag.

Comment: Things that are thread_local are guaranteed to be initialized before use, in this case `generate` is first false.

Comment: You need to read up on logical or boolean expressions in C++.   Given that `generate` is a `bool`, the expression `generate = !generate` has the same net effect as `if (generate) generate = false; else generate = true`.   If generate is of other numeric type, then it has the same net effect as `if (generate != 0) generate = 0; else generate = 1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier ... `thread_local` (since C++11) have ... thread (since C++11) storage duration but **are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration**

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So when the function is called the first time, the `generate` variable will be [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) which for `thread_local` variables means [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization). Zero initialization for a `bool` variable means it will be set to `false`, and for a `double` it will be `0.0`.

Comment: Interesting. So basically, this generate variable flips the variable used from z1 to z0? Every call to generateGaussianNoise uses either z0 or the previously generated z1

Comment: @user3180 Yes, if `generate` is used to select one of the two.

Comment: Reading this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization make me think 'generate' is not initialized and therefore indetermined.

Comment: @Surt If you scroll down to [the notes section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization#Notes) you will see that it says "static and thread-local objects get zero initialized".

Answer (score 1):

It's a quick way to flip a `bool` variable from `true` to `false` and vice versa. It avoids having to write:

```
if (generate)
    generate = false;
else
    generate = true;
```

As for the initialization of `generate`, thread-local variables get [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). For a `bool` that means `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`thread_local` is type of storage duration; new to C++11. It's the same as `static` except you get a new instance of the variable per-thread.

Like `static`, a `thread_local` `bool` type is initialised automatically to `false`.

`generate = !generate;` flips that value, and that value is retained on a per-thread basis for a subsequent invocation of that function.

I wouldn't recommend generating Guassian random numbers in this manner though - the technique is painfully slow (sampling with rejection is faster). The code in the link you cite is terrible - for starters `rand()` is not thread safe so all this `thread_local` stuff is a nonsense. And the use of `std::numeric_limits<...>::min()` for an "epsilon" shows minimal understanding of floating point properties.

There's no need to program at this low level; C++11 has Box-Muller built in to it's much-improved random number libraries.

Answer (score 0):

`generate` is acting as a flag variable, which toggles as per need. It is analogous to

```
if (generate == True)
  generate = False
else
  generate = True
```

For the second part of the code, where

> How can this code work if z1 is not assigned until AFTER this piece of code?

As it is a return statement, this must be a part of some function or so, and hence `z1` must be defined in the calling function and its value passed to the called function.